# Add an IF into CSV filtering loop

Tags: csv, powershell

I've got the following code and have been trying to add an `IF` statement so that if the item is not found, write the text NotFound.

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv D:\MaintenanceWindow2.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv D:\ScomAlerts.csv    
$csv1 | Where {$field = $_.Computername;($csv2 | where {$_.Computername -eq $field})}
```

-Edit, here is what I currently have but it doesn't seem to pick every server.

```
Import-Csv D:\2.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $table[$_.Computername] = $_.'Collection Name'}

$Global:result = $AlertDataNoDupe | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject] @{ 

Server=$_.NetbiosComputerName

MaintenanceWindow=IF($table[$_.NetbiosComputerName]){$table[$_.NetbiosComputerName]}

                ELSE{"Not found!"}
}
```

-Edit, adding sample data

MaintenanceWindow2.csv:

```
"Computername","Collection Name"
"Server1","NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Cert - Thu 2:00"
"Server2","NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Cert - Thu 2:00"
```

ScomAlerts.csv:

```
ComputerName
Server2
Server3
```

Comment: Consider using `Compare-Object` for something like this. It will tell you the differences.

Comment: I wasn't able to put together anything that accomplished what this did, being a novice.

Comment: Have a look at the output from `Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2`

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You never use a hashtable. The sample and text doesn't match.

Comment: Apologies, that was from sample code I used.  I'll edit the question since the `$hash = @{}` does not seem to be needed.

Comment: This could have been simply done by changing the last line to a `Switch` statement. `Switch($csv1){{$csv2.computername -contains $_.computername}{$_;continue};default{"System not found: " + $_.computername}}`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I'm unable to export the output of the `Switch` statement into anything meaningful.

Comment: Your sample should work as long as the variables `$AlertDataNoDupe` and `$table` exists and `NetbiosComputerName` is the correct property. See updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script in your updated question should work fine. The only changes I would make is to use `$table.ContainsKey("")` and use indents, but that's mostly for readability.

```
$MaintenanceWindows = @"
"Computername","Collection Name"
"Server1","NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Cert - Thu 2:00"
"Server2","NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Cert - Thu 2:00"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$ScomAlerts = @"
ComputerName
Server2
Server3
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#Create hashtable
$table = @{}
#Add MWs to hashtable
$MaintenanceWindows | ForEach-Object { $table.Add(($_.ComputerName.Split(".")[0].Trim()), $_.'Collection Name')}

$Global:result = $ScomAlerts | ForEach-Object {
    $computer = $_.ComputerName.Split(".")[0].Trim()

    [PSCustomObject] @{ 
        Server = $computer
        MaintenanceWindow = if($table.ContainsKey($computer)){
            $table[$computer]
        } else{ "Not found!" }
    }

}

$result

Server  MaintenanceWindow                               
------  -----------------                               
Server2 NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Cert - Thu 2:00
Server3 Not found!
```

or

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $MaintenanceWindows -DifferenceObject $ScomAlerts -Property Computername -IncludeEqual -PassThru |
Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -match '==|=>' } |
Select-Object ComputerName, @{n="Collection Name";e={ if($_."Collection Name"){ $_."Collection Name" } else { "Not Found!" } }}

Computername Collection Name                                 
------------ ---------------                                 
Server2      NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Cert - Thu 2:00
Server3      Not Found!
```

Comment: Thank you, might I point out the point of the question was to add text that indicated a match was not found.  This command returns 149 matches and the DifferenceObject contains 196.

Comment: See updated answer. This will output the difference in both. Do you only want the ones unique to `$csv2`? Because you sample above would only output `$csv1` objects (that match btw)..

Comment: Managed to come this far, `$diff` contains the Compare-Object results, I use two `Where` filters to create a `$total` variable.  However the `Foreach-Object` above outputs the results to the ComputerName column.  I'm struggling to get that output into the second column.

Comment: Now that we've seen what you want, I've provided a tuned edition of your code (yours should have worked btw) and an alternative using `Compare-Object`. Personally I would have chosen the hashtable-solution considering you have one source with `Computername`-property and one with `NetbiosComputerName` which `Compare-Object` doesn't like.  What do you mean it doesn't pick every server? Your code would only display servers from `$AlertDataNoDupe` which is what you're code is written to do. What's missing from the output?

Comment: A spot check revealed items marked as `NotFound` were in fact present in the CSV containing the MaintenanceWindow data.  Also, I tried `ContainsKey` but didn't get consistent results.  Very strange.

Comment: Then one of your csv-files has an error. Since you know which computer is missing, then compare the computername-field in the csv-file in both files. Is one netbios-name (s1) while the other is fqdn (s1.foo.bar)? Does the computer have a leading or trailing whitespace in one of the files? I've updated the hashtable-sample above to include `Trim()` and `Split()` to handle both those cases, but there may be something else different in the computername-properties so check the csv-files. :-)

Comment: My apologies!  The previous attempt at this seemed to miss servers which were in the MaintenanceWindow CSV.  This new attempt looks to be spot on, I'm going to work on comparing the data but the NetBiosComputerName output from SCOM is just that, a server name no FQDN.